# Is there an API to access a corporate contact list in Office 365?

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

I'm tasked with developing an application for a client that -- amongst it's other functionality -- retrieves data from their corporate contact list in Office 365.  Are there any APIs that let me access that list -- preferably without needing a user to login each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > corporate contact list

Depends where the actual list is held ? eg

Are the Mail-Enabled Contacts in the Global Address list - if so you could use the Azure Graph API, The new People API https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/people-rest-operations, Or you could use FindPeople in EWS https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj191039(v=exchg.150).aspx. Or you could even use Remote Powershell and Get-MailContact

If its held in a Public Folder then use EWS eg FindItems on the particular public Folder

If its in a Mailbox Contact Folder then REST https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/contacts-rest-operations or EWS

Comment: Sounds like I need more discussion with the client.  Thanks.